# Index.ios.js -> Index.js for react-relay Super expression must either be null or a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, relay

I'm learning Replay and React following: http://www.mot.la/2016-05-08-getting-started-with-react-native-and-relay.html

The example uses Index.ios.js which has been deprecated to now use Index.js. However I'm having some issues with my imports... I think

```
Unhandled JS Exception: Super expression must either be null or a function, not undefined
```

my Index.js file

```
// Note: I noticed that you imported Component from the wrong place. That might also be contributing to your issue so I fixed it here.
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Relay, { 
  Route,
  RootContainer,
  DefaultNetworkLayer
} from 'react-relay'

// Relay.injectNetworkLayer(new DefaultNetworkLayer('http://localhost:3000/graphiql'))

class UserRoute extends Route {
  static paramDefinitions = {
    userID: { required: true }
  }
  static queries = {
    user: () => Relay.QL`
      query { 
        user(id: $userID)
      }
    `
  }
  static routeName = 'UserRoute'
}

class UserInfo extends Component {
  render () {
    const user = this.props.user
    return (
      <Text>email: {user.email}</Text>
    )
  }
}

UserInfo = Relay.createContainer(UserInfo, {
  fragments: {
    user: () => Relay.QL`
      fragment on User {
        id,
        email
      }
    `
  }
})


class RelayApp extends Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>
          Welcome to React Native!
        </Text>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>
          To get started, edit index.ios.js
        </Text>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>
          Press Cmd+R to reload,{'\n'}
          Cmd+D or shake for dev menu
        </Text>
        <RootContainer
          Component={UserInfo}
          route={new UserRoute({userID: '1'})}
          renderFetched={(data) => <UserInfo {...this.props} {...data} />}
        />
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated